# Name cannot begin with the ' ' character, in ARB Request

Tags: php, xml, authorize.net, authorize.net-arb

I have used the ARB in authorize.net, I am using the php and Xml to request for create subscriptions in ARB.Its working fine in local but i uploaded the files in server it is showing following error,

**Error message**: Name cannot begin with the ' ' character, hexadecimal value 0x20. Line 1, position 406.

**Error Code**: E00003

Could anyone please suggest how to resolve the issue, did i have to contact server?

Below is the Xml file i have used to request,

```
$content ="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" .
        "<ARBCreateSubscriptionRequest xmlns=\"AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd\">" .
        "<merchantAuthentication>".
        "<name>5A3RXdSct55</name>".
        "<transactionKey>" . $transactionkey . "</transactionKey>".
        "</merchantAuthentication>".
        "<refId>" .$refId . "</refId>".
        "<subscription>".
        "<name>Monthly Subscription</name>".
        "<paymentSchedule>".
        "<interval>".
        "<length>". $length ."</length>".
        "<unit>". $unit ."</unit>".
        "</interval>".
        "<startDate>" . $startDate . "</startDate>".
        "<totalOccurrences>". $totalOccurrences . "</totalOccurrences>".
        "<trialOccurrences>". $trialOccurrences . "</trialOccurrences>".
        "</paymentSchedule>".
        "<amount>". $amount ."</amount>".
        "<trialAmount>" . $trialAmount . "</trialAmount>".
        "<payment>".
        "<creditCard>".
        "<cardNumber>" . $cardNumber . "</cardNumber>".
        "<expirationDate>" . $expirationDate . "</expirationDate>".
        "</creditCard>".
        "</payment>".
        "<billTo>".
        "<firstName>". $firstName . "</firstName>".
        "<lastName>" . $lastName . "</lastName>".
        "<company>" . $company . "</company>".
        "<address>" . $address . "</address>".
        "<city>" . $city . "</city>".
        "<state>" . $state . "</state>".
        "<zip>" . $zipcode . "</zip>".
        "<country>" . $country . "</country>".
        "</billTo>".
        "<shipTo>".
        "<firstName>". $firstName . "</firstName>".
        "<lastName>" . $lastName . "</lastName>".
        "<company>" . $company . "</company>".
        "<address>" . $address . "</address>".
        "<city>" . $city . "</city>".
        "<state>" . $state . "</state>".
        "<zip>" . $zipcode . "</zip>".
        "<country>" . $country . "</country>".
        "</shipTo>".
        "</subscription>".
        "</ARBCreateSubscriptionRequest>";
```

Comment: That code looks ok. Is the value for `<Name>` hardcoded like we see it here? Or is it provided by a variable?

Comment: Yes John, it is Hardcoded and the Name tag under subscription tag is provided by variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the solution by using xml validator, i made a mistake in the `$startdate` variable it holds the date function, I haven't added the `<?php` tag to the date function.

By using `<?php` it resolved the problem. Thanks for the suggestion cartalot.

Comment: great! yeah will say again if you are taking values straight from a form like a billing form -- some kind of trim and prep for xml function is very necessary. definitely test your form putting in characters like < / etc to make sure they are removed - otherwise your xml will break.

Answer (score 0):

pass all the values through php trim() first like

```
 $firstName = trim($firstName) ; 
 $lastName = trim($lastName) ;
```

then pass to your form
Also -- and this might not be appropriate for what you are doing but wanted to pass on - you can make the xml string without all the dot concatenation like

```
 "<billTo>
   <firstName>$firstName</firstName>
    <lastName>$lastName</lastName>" ;
```

if you are doing this with php - php will process the $variables inside a double quote and output as the text values.